# using string values from resources.resx

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to use resources.resx file for storing string. I have created resources.resx file in Properties and created a sample string with name st.To use it i have written following code-

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Brand_Boyz.Properties"
```

and using text block text value as

but it give error saying Static is not supported in windows Silverlight Project.
So how do I use it?

Comment: "and using text block text value as" text as what??

Answer (score -1):

You can use [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2010/09/16/content-or-resource-files-another-way-to-load-a-static-xml-file-to-your-application.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb298331(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
TextReader sr = new StringReader("<Root><Child/></Root>");
XElement xmlTree = XElement.Load(sr);
sr.Close();
Console.WriteLine(xmlTree);
```